# Ampscript and IF statement to get data from two different data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, email-template, content-builder

I have two data extensions:

- Data extension 1: `API_Onboarding_OnlineMemberships` has the following column: `SUBS_START_DATE` (this DE gets the emails)
- Data extension 2: `Customers` has the following column: `DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST`

Here's the amp script I've updated in the email:

```
%%[
SET @SUBS_START_DATE = Lookup("API_Onboarding_OnlineMemberships","SUBS_START_DATE","CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID", @CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID)
SET @DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST = Lookup("Customers","DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST","CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID", @CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID)

IF @SUBS_START_DATE > @DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST THEN
  SET @output = "Welcome Back"
ELSE
  SET @output = "Welcome"
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@output)=%%
```

It should show 'Welcome Back' if @Subs_Start_Date is today and the @Date_of_first_sub_aest is yesterday...

@CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID is the Subscriber key for both data extensions, but not necessarily the primary key for both.

This ampscript doesn't render the right data i.e., Welcome or Welcome back email. Am I missing something?
[image]

Comment: you can do lookups from any data extensions and work with IF statements based on the results. So sure this works. https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible and is something that happens fairly often. See below for example of how to do this:

```ampscript
%%[
SET @subsDate = Lookup("Test1","Subs_Date","MyPrimaryKeyName",@myPrimaryKeyValue)
SET @dateOfFirstSub = Lookup("Test2","Date_of_first_Sub","MyPrimaryKeyName",@myPrimaryKeyValue)

IF @subsDate > @dateOfFirstSub THEN
  SET @output = "Welcome"
ELSE
  SET @output = "Welcome Back"
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@output)=%%
```

This gathers the values from each DE based off your primarykey (which is being used as a foreign key to match based on the shared relationship) to determine the row that houses this information. It then compares these variables to determine the output (which I pushed to a variable `@output` for the example, but you can also use Output() function or close the AMPscript block and write as HTML, etc. and then open the next block for the ELSE statement.

I then output the output variable via an inline call of the v() function that then says either 'Welcome' or 'Welcome Back' depending on the values in the 2 lookup vars.

Comment: Thanks @gortonington I've edited my question with the updated query, following your recommendations. But it still doesn't show the right data. Do you have any recommendations for this?

Comment: Can you share sample outputs of the two lookups? Also are these being stored as strings or dates in the DEs? Is there a timezone difference? If you provide more info @PrekshaRathore, I may be able to better assist as I do not believe it is the code at this point, but more likely something with the data

Comment: Thank you Gortonington.
I've added a screenshot of how the fields look like in the data extension. As seen, the setting for Subs_start_date is 'Date'. Also, in the data extension, the date comes something like this: 'Sunday, 20 March 2022 12:00 AM' - potentially that's an issue.

Comment: Thanks @PrekshaRathore - but is `DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST` also a date field or a string?  If it is a string, then that is likely the issue you are facing. and if it is a string can you give an example of output (and format - e.g. DD.MM.YYYY). Other thing to note is if the foreign key of `CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_NS_ID` has more than 1 entry in either DE, it will use whichever it finds first as the value to return in the Lookup - which could create discrepancy on outputs.

Comment: Thanks, @Gortonington.  `DATE_OF_FIRST_SUB_AEST` is also a 'Date' field in the second data extension. The date format here for this field is the same 'Sunday, 28 December 2014 12:00 AM'. Each data extension has only one record for the specific Customer_Internal_NS_ID. I think it's got to do something with the Day being mentioned in the date.

Comment: I've tried a few different variations of the IF statement for one data extension itself (instead of two). And for some reason, SFMC is picking up two different dates as the same date. I think that's the issue - it's not identifying two different columns with different dates as being different.

Comment: I tried something like `IF @END_DATE_AEST != @today
THEN  SET @output = "Welcome Back"
ELSE
  SET @output = "Welcome"
ENDIF` and it still says Welcome even though it shouldn't.

Comment: @PrekshaRathore - I get the feeling it is taking the dates and for some reason turning them into Strings. Try wrapping them in StringToDate() - `StringToDate(@subsDate) > StringToDate(@dateOfFirstSub)` and see if that helps to force a date comparison...Seems odd though why that would be happening. Could also try DateParse() AMPscript function as well to force datetime data type.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington. StringToDate worked! Thank you :)

Comment: is there a way to write that if records from data extension 1 does not exist in data extension 2, then show this? Would that require a different query? Or I can just edit the existing IF statement?